# Add a year column during rbindlist

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I am reading a large number of .csv files into a single dataframe. I have had great help on SO already as the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76872882/18499579) shows.

```
library(data.table)
files.to.read <- list.files(path = "./data", 
                            pattern = ".*\\.csv$", 
                            full.names = TRUE, 
                            recursive = FALSE)
L <- lapply(files.to.read, fread)
DT <- rbindlist(L, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

My datasets do not have a variable that marks the year that the observation is made, instead that is contained in the file name e.g. asdf_19.csv where 19 refers to 2019.

Starting from the code above, I want to add in something that will create a new column in the final dataframe that marks the relevant number from the end of the document name that it came from.

At the moment my best option is just adding this manually for each file, but I would love to avoid doing that...

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this might work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59875805/6851825

Comment: I think it'd be as easy as `rbindlist(L, use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE, idcol="newid")`, which will create an integer column named `newid` that indexes along `files.to.read`. If you want to be a little fancy, though, you can use `L <- lapply(setNames(nm=files.to.read), fread)`, and then do `rbindlist(..., idcol="filename")` and the new `filename` column will contain the file name itself (not an integer/index).

Answer (score 1):

I quite like using `purrr::enframe` for this (after applying names to a list):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

dir.create("fake_data")

2014:2018 |> 
  walk(\(year) write_csv(tibble(a = 1:100), file.path("fake_data", paste0("yr_", year, ".csv"))))


files.to.read <- list.files(path = "fake_data", 
                            pattern = ".*\\.csv$", 
                            full.names = TRUE, 
                            recursive = FALSE)

L <- lapply(files.to.read, fread)

names(L) <- str_extract(files.to.read, "\\d*(?=\\.csv)")

L |> 
  enframe("year", "data") |> 
  unnest(data)
#> # A tibble: 500 × 2
#>    year      a
#>    <chr> <int>
#>  1 2014      1
#>  2 2014      2
#>  3 2014      3
#>  4 2014      4
#>  5 2014      5
#>  6 2014      6
#>  7 2014      7
#>  8 2014      8
#>  9 2014      9
#> 10 2014     10
#> # ℹ 490 more rows
```